# Why does python still shows version after being removed?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have uninstalled python completed from my windows 10 and even deleted all its path from environment variables **but it is runnning python -V and showing Python 2.7.14 which was never there**.
I want to remove this 2.7.14 but it is not present anywhere on my system.

When i run python in command line it gives ImportError: No module named site which is OK(since i have uninstalled python).
But after running python --version it shows Python 2.7.14 which was never there in the first place. the only python i had was python 3.7.6 which i have installed.

python on cmd gives
ImportError: No module named site 
while
python -V gives
Python 2.7.14

Comment: "which was never there". Well, it looks like it actually was. The trick will be to find the executable for this Python version, and uninstall/remove that as well.

Comment: Try `python -vv` and look if you can find the directory in the output.

Comment: Where have you looked for Python 2.7? Only more recent versions of Python get installed in C:\Program Files. You probably have a folder C:\Python27 which was the previous standard location.  Nonexistent programs do not report their version.

Comment: No, I don't have any folder C:\python 27. Even I don't have any trace of it.

Comment: I have a question.  Why are you doing this?  You can install Python 3 and make the `python` command point to it; see https://superuser.com/questions/1576758/how-do-i-alias-python3-on-windows.  Python 2.7 doesn't need to be uninstalled to do that!

Answer (score 2):

Open a command prompt and type `where python.exe`:

```
C:\Users\partner>where notepad.exe
C:\Windows\System32\notepad.exe
C:\Windows\notepad.exe
```

If it is in your path this should find it for you.

Comment: where python.exe gives
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE\python.exe.. I am more confused now. How come MySql comes with python??

Comment: @JaiSipani Because it supports it for stored procedures, probably. This kind of feature is not unusual.

Comment: And ... hence ... uninstalling Python 2.7 entirely would break MySQL Workbench.  Consider whether you really want to do this.

Comment: As for why; see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-scripting-shell-window.html for an example.  Also https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-what-is-new-8.html which says: *"With Python 2 reaching end-of-life, MySQL Workbench 8.0.23 is the first release to use Python 3 for scripting-related features ..."*.  So Upgrading to WB 8.0.23 or later is probably a good idea!